# How to retrieve tweets from Twitter API over different times of a day

Tags: php, twitter

I am using php to retrieve tweets from twitter API that contain the keyword google.

```
$query = urlencode("google" . " since:2016-11-02 -filter:retweets"); 
$search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=$query&count=100&Lang=en";
```

this code return the most recent 100 tweets (in the past 2-3 minutes)
How can I modify the query so it retrieves 100 tweets related to google over different times of the day

Comment: I don't think the twitter api allows for time specific queries, perhaps set your script to be called by cron at timed intervals?

Comment: Can you please be more specific and provide an example. Thank you